# Es posible usar una sentencia Select como alias?

Tags: oracle

como dice el titulo , es posible utilizar una sentencia select como alias en Oracle ,
es decir:

```
Select anio as(select anio from tabla1)
from tabla1;
```

y que en la salida me de como reslutado
el año en el encabezado de la columna

```
2019   <-- Encabezado de columna
----
2019
```

saludos.

Comment: Al hacer la consulta ¿qué error o advertencia arroja? Me refiero al mensaje de salida.

Comment: Cada SGBD tiene sus peculiaridades, pero el SQL sigue siendo el mismo. Supongo que no se podrá hacer como lo tienes planteado, pero debe haber alguna manera.

Comment: Respuesta rápida No. Lo único parecido a lo que buscas podría ser construir directamente la sentencia SQL de forma dinámica.

Comment: como seria contruirla de forma dinamica? @PatricioMoracho

Comment: Sería constuir una cadena con el Query a ejecutar y a partir del `anio` colocar los titulos de las columnas y por último ejecutas la sentencia SQL.

Comment: puedes poner un ejemplo de tu tabla y el ejemeplo que quieres que salga de la consulta?